# Did the meaning of the n parameter of fgets change over time?

Tags: c, fgets

The [Apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/SecureCodingGuide/Articles/BufferOverflows.html) states:

> **Security Note for `fgets`**: Although the `fgets` function provides the ability to read a limited amount of data, you must be careful when using it. Like the other functions in the “safer” column, `fgets` always terminates the string. However, unlike the other functions in that column, it takes a maximum number of bytes to read, not a buffer size.

The last sentence sounds wrong to me. For comparison, here is [what POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html):

> The `fgets()` function shall read bytes from stream into the array pointed to by `s` until `n-1` bytes are read, or a `<newline>` is read and transferred to `s`, or an end-of-file condition is encountered. A null byte shall be written immediately after the last byte read into the array.

Here is what [an ISO C draft from 2005 says](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> The `fgets` function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by `n` from the stream pointed to by `stream` into the array pointed to by `s`. No additional characters are read after a new-line character (which is retained) or after end-of-file. A null character is written immediately after the last character read into the array.

The FreeBSD man page says the same as the C standard and POSIX.

This makes me think that the Apple documentation is clearly wrong. The simplest explanation is that Apple didn't know better when they published this article. But although simple, this hypothesis doesn't feel plausible to me.

Are there other reasons that Apple could deviate from the wording of the C standard?

Comment: That document is just wrong. The man page has it right.

Comment: More accurately : either the documentation is wrong or the `fgets` implementation is non-compliant. I'm guessing it's the former.

Comment: POSIX seems very clear: "until n-1 bytes are read"

Answer (score 2):

Even early (early 1970s) versions of `fgets()` specified that `n` is the buffer size, and that the buffer will be terminated with a `'\0'`.

Kernighan and Ritchie reflected that correctly in all their books and documentation.

However, a number of authors of introductory texts (who I won't attempt to name, since I'm sure I'll miss some, and all deserve to be equally embarrassed) documented that up to `n` characters could be written to the buffer, and that the trailing `'\0'` might be dropped in some cases.

Comment: I only know of one author who would write such nonsense, and indeed, his book contains the mistake. :) Good to know he's not the only one.

Answer (score 1):

The [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) functions reads *at most* the size minus one bytes from the file. If the wrong value is passed as the buffer size then `fgets` might write out of bounds.

So the quote from the Apple documentation *that you show* is correct in that the value is more related to the number of bytes to read from the file. But on the other hand any normal code would use the actual buffer size when falling `fgets`. And if that number is input from a user then it should be validated before use.

On the other hand the documentation continues to state (thanks for the note Sander De Dycker)

> In practical terms, this means that you must always pass a size value that is one fewer than the size of the buffer to leave room for the null termination. If you do not, the `fgets` function will dutifully terminate the string past the end of your buffer, potentially overwriting whatever byte of data follows it.

And *this* is wrong. The size argument passed to `fgets` always includes the string terminator. At least according to the C standard.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. Your reference is not as normative as the two I gave in my question, and I think it even contains wrong information. My question is about _why_ Apple might have published this wrong information.